# extracting and formatting a macAddress from buffer

Tags: node.js

I am trying to extract and format a mac address from a buffer as 00:04:a3:01:02:90

`> const buffer = Buffer.from([0x00,0x04,0xa3,0x01,0x02,0x90]);`

`> console.log(buffer)`

`<Buffer 00 04 a3 01 02 90>`

`> console.log (buffer.slice(0, 6).map(byte => byte.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join(':'));`

`0:4:0:1:2:90`

The output I am getting is removing the leading 0s and incorrectly displaying the third hex element 0xa3.

How do I correctly extract and format the bytes the mac address -> 00:04:a3:01:02:90?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting buffer into HEX string and then some string manipulation can give you the expected MAC Address. Try this script:

```js
const buffer = Buffer.from([0x00,0x04,0xa3,0x01,0x02,0x90]);
const bufferString = buffer.toString('hex')
const macAddress = bufferString.split(/(..)/).filter(s => s).join(":")
console.log(macAddress)
```